# How to construct personalized permutations

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-itertools

I want to create a set of permutations of a given list , say `a = np.array([0,1,2])`. I am aware of `itertools.permutations`, but I need something that I can personalized so my permutations follows certain rules.

For instance such a rule could be that 1 cannot be the second element. Creating all permutations using itertools and test them all for the rule's compliance would take too much time.

So I think I need a function to create permutations by myself but I have no idea how to do that. Could you help me writing a function that take a list as parameter and return all possible permutations of that list ? Then I will be able to modify it so the permutations meet my rules.

Comment: What's the question here?  Right now it just seems to be a request for someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As explained by @Mr.T, `itertools` is a C library.

This means that calling `itertools.permutations` first, then filtering may be faster than implementing your own "optimized" function in python.

Ideally, you'd implement your "optimized" function in C, and call it from python.

For the sake of completeness, here's an equivalent source code from `itertools` that you can modify according to your needs :

```
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    # permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
    # permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(n))
    cycles = list(range(n, n-r, -1))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return
```

Details :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

If you feel like implementing C code and using it in python :

> Any code that we write using any compiled language like C, C++, or
> Java can be integrated or imported into Python. This code is
> considered as an “extension.” A Python extension module is nothing
> more than a normal C library. On Unix machines, these libraries
> usually end in .so (for shared object). On Windows machines, you
> typically see .dll (for dynamically linked library).
>
> details : https://medium.com/practo-engineering/execute-python-code-at-the-speed-of-c-extending-python-93e081b53f04